# unsigned vs. signed issue for bitwise NOT and compare

Tags: arduino

After a bit of head scratching, I've determined that signed and unsigned chars have a surprising difference when it comes to == signs.

```
void loop()
{
}

void setup()
{
  unsigned char ucA = 0x55;
  unsigned char ucB = 0xAA;
  unsigned char ucB_not;

  char cA = 0x55;
  char cB = 0xAA;

  Serial.begin( 115200);

  if ( ucA == ~ucB)
    Serial.println( "unsigned -- match");
  else
    Serial.println( "unsigned -- no match");


  if ( cA == ~cB)
    Serial.println( "signed -- match");
  else
    Serial.println( "signed -- no match");

  ucB_not = ~ucB;
  if ( ucA == ucB_not)
    Serial.println( "unsigned, seperate variable -- match");
  else
    Serial.println( "unsigned, seperate variable -- no match");

}
```

The output I get is:

```
unsigned -- no match
signed -- match
unsigned, seperate variable -- match
```

Is there some rule that the values get widened before the compare?  Even if so, the **unsigned** case should not be a problem, should it?

I've added the last case -- creating a seperate variable seems to not have the problem.

I'm using the Arduino release 1.0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both C and C++, the operands of operators which are integer types narrower than int gets [promoted to an int](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion).  If the smaller type is signed, then the promoted type is sign extended - the signed char value `-x` is promoted to a signed int with the same value `-x`, which in 2's complement machines means prefixing it with some `0xff` bytes. If the result of an operation is assigned back to the smaller type, it is truncated.

Your three cases apply these rules as follows:

1. Unsigned char `0xaa` is promoted to unsigned int `0x00aa` and unsigned char `0x55` to unsigned int `0x0055`. Inverting `0x00aa` gives `0xff55` which is not equal to `0x0055`.
2. Signed char `0xaa` is promoted to signed int `0xffaa` ( negative signed value is sign extended - signed char value `-86` is promoted to signed int value `-86` ) and signed char `0x55` to signed int `0x0055` (positive signed char value `+85` is promoted to signed int value `+85` ). Inverting `0xffaa` gives `0x0055` which is equal to `0x0055`.
3. Unsigned char `0xaa` is promoted to unsigned int `0x00aa`, inverted to `0xff55` then stored as an unsigned char, causing it to be truncated to `0x55`. The unsigned char `0x55` is later compared with the unsigned char `0x55` and found to be equal.